# Ray-tracing (or casting) between rays and STL file

Tags: python, mesh, raycasting, raytracing

I have a 3D shape (a bone) as a triangular mesh in STL format and I'm working with Python language.

I then have a ray with its origin and direction and I need to know:

- which face of the mesh collides with this ray
- coordinates of intersection point
- the angle between my ray and the normal vector of the collided face

I know 'pycaster' ( https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/ray-casting-with-python-and-vtk-intersecting-linesrays-with-surface-meshes/ ) but it only works with Python 2.x and I need to use Python 3.x.

I know 'trimeshgeom' class ( http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/_sources/trimeshgeom.txt ) from cgkit but PyCharm can't install it as an interpreter (can't understand why).

Does anybody know how I could do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,
Cheers,

Davide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar task once and ended up implementing the rather simple
[Möller-Trumbore-Algorithm](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/moller-trumbore-ray-triangle-intersection).

The code can be stolen from [printrun](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/blob/master/printrun/stltool.py#L47):

```
def ray_triangle_intersection(ray_near, ray_dir, v123):
    """
    Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm in pure python
    Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm
    """
    v1, v2, v3 = v123
    eps = 0.000001
    edge1 = v2 - v1
    edge2 = v3 - v1
    pvec = numpy.cross(ray_dir, edge2)
    det = edge1.dot(pvec)
    if abs(det) < eps:
        return False, None
    inv_det = 1. / det
    tvec = ray_near - v1
    u = tvec.dot(pvec) * inv_det
    if u < 0. or u > 1.:
        return False, None
    qvec = numpy.cross(tvec, edge1)
    v = ray_dir.dot(qvec) * inv_det
    if v < 0. or u + v > 1.:
        return False, None

    t = edge2.dot(qvec) * inv_det
    if t < eps:
        return False, None

return True, t
```

For the angle calculation you can use e.g. `angle_between_vectors()` from [transformations.py](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html)

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply.
Do you know what is 't'?

Comment: The fact here is that this function works for 1 ray and 1 face. If I have a lot of rays and a lot of faces, I have to iterate this function a million time. 
Do you know if exists anything more efficient and less time consuming?
Thanks,

Comment: True, we re-wrote this to be a vectorized function to take numpy arrays for triangles and rays of arbitrary shape in the end. After that we used that function in parallel threads. Still not fast enough. Then we ported exactly this code to CUDA and since then we are running it on the GPU. :)

Comment: If I remember correctly it was a fun task to vectorize this and we ended up with five dimensional arrays :)

Comment: and do you know what 't' is (the returned value together with true)?

Comment: and also, do you know how I can find intersection point?

Thanks,
Davide

Comment: `t` and the intersection point are related. As you can see in the link in the code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm), `t` is the parameter of a point-vector equation of a line.

Comment: You can google for "parametric form of the equation of a line"

Comment: This webpage is a good introduction on how to vectorize calculations: https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#code-vectorization

Comment: Now I understood how to calculate intersection point from 't'. Thank you